# Commutators and transitive group of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a $n$-transitive permutation group of a finite set $X$. Let $\alpha\ne id_X\in G$ be permutation that fixes $k$ elements of $X$. What other condition is needed to ensure that there exists $\beta\in G$ such that the commutator of $\alpha,\beta$ is not equal to the identity? Is there a formulaic way to construct this $\beta$?

**Edit:**

I want to be able to mimic the construction of $\tau$ used in the proof of Lemma 2.4 on p.2 of the following document for $n$-transitive  permutation groups: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/Ansimple.pdf

Comment: Is there a relation between $n,k,|X|$? Also I take it that $\alpha$ fixes *exactly* $k$ elements? One possibility then: $|X|<n+k$ then such a $\beta$ exists.

Comment: You are asking for a condition that ensures that $\alpha \not\in Z(G)$. Well $n \ge 1$ and $k >0$ is a sufficient condition for that.